# SAS: running outside program in batch file

Tags: sas

I try to run a program in SAS using batch mode. So I created a controlfile in SAS and wrote out as outfile(txt file). The nI wrote a code to make a bat file(proram1.bat) to run the proram but I don't get output file. the program is located at c:program files\programx. I wan t output file to be in C:\program1.out file. Anything wrong here?

data *null*;

file "C:\program1.bat";

put 'C:';

put "CD C:\program files\programx";

put "programx C:\program1.con C:\program1.out";

run;

options xmin noxwait;

x "C:\program1.bat";

Answer (score 0):

When I replicate your code I get a valid bat file after SAS executes:

```
C:
CD C:\program files\programx
programx C:\program1.con C:\program1.out
```

which I manually modified:

```
C:
CD C:\program files\programx
dir
:::programx C:\program1.con C:\program1.out
pause
```

I see no problems on the SAS side.

Comment: thank you rshdev for the verification. I will look into what is wrong with other stuff.